# Simulating sun 3d direction

Tags: directx, lighting

At the moment I got the following to simulate the suns direction:

```
void Sun::Update()
{
    if (!mIsMoving)
        return;

    const auto now = Clock::now();
    const auto timeDiff = now - mTimeStart;
    const float count = std::chrono::duration_cast<Intervall>(timeDiff).count();

    assert(mNightDayRatio <= 1.0f);
    if (count >= 0.5f + 0.5f * mNightDayRatio)
        mTimeStart = now;

    const float angle = count * glm::two_pi<float>() - glm::pi<float>();

    mDirLight.mLightDirection = Vec3(glm::cos(angle), glm::sin(angle), glm::sin(angle));
}
```

The problem is at the extremes the shadows from the sun (a directional light) become really "distorted"/"too long". I don't need a terribly complex solution just something that gives somewhat realistic sun direction over time.

Any ideas?

Comment: When the light is shining nearly-parallel to the surface, shadows can get arbitrarily long. So changing the way you calculate the light direction won't prevent this, unless you forbid the sun from rising/setting (the times when its direction is closest to parallel to the ground plane). You could however mask the effect, by increasing the attenuation of the light at glancing angles by more than the normal n-dot-l, so that the whole surface falls into darkness before the shadows exceed a certain proportion.